# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner Closed error with java assignment

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed at 1070,1334. Java returned 1
```

This code reads from a `Course.txt` file located in the project folder, and after starting to read the text before finishing the first line it has this exception error. I am lost as this is the first time I have created a Java program for this.

I have double checked errors on netbeans with no help, also I tried removing and replacing certain areas of the code with no success.

```
package u2a1_readtextfilehandleexcep;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
//@author jeff thurston
public class U2A1_ReadTextFileHandleExcep {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO code application logic here
System.out.println("U2A1 Java Read Text File");

try 
    { 
    java.io.File file1 = new java.io.File("Course.txt");

Scanner input = new Scanner(file1);
while (input.hasNext())
  {
    String coursecode = input.next();
      int coursehours = input.nextInt();
     String coursetitle = input.next();
System.out.println ("Course code =  " + coursecode + " - 
Credit Hours = " + coursehours + " - " + "Course Title = " + 
coursetitle);
input.close();
  }
    }
catch (IOException e)
  {
 System.out.println ("Error in reading the file" + 
e.getMessage()); 
    }
}
}
```

It should run as follows:

```
U2A1 Java Read Text File
Course code = IT2249 - Credit Hours = 6 - Course Title = Introduction to Programming with Java
Course code = IT2230 - Credit Hours = 3 - Course Title = Introduction to Database Systems
Course code = IT4789 - Credit Hours = 3 - Course Title = Mobile Cloud Computing Application Development
```

However after `Course Title = Introduction` in the first line is where the system stops producing output.

Comment: Move `input.close();` from the last line of your `while` loop to **outside** the `while` loop. And your formatting is terrible.

Comment: Elliott, I have tried moving it outside with the same exact results, sorry for the formatting it was from adding it into the webpage.

Comment: copy the beginning of the Course.txt file so we can see how it looks like. Are all values on the same line?

Comment: IT2249 6 Introduction to Programming with Java
IT2230 3 Introduction to Database Systems
IT4789 3 Mobile Cloud Computing Application Development

Comment: I fixed the error. Thank you guys for helping me with the little fixes. the wording in the txt file needed to be connected via _ to fix it. thanks again

Comment: @jeffreythurston You did not get exactly the same result. Either you didn't move it or you did move it but didn't recompile.